# Creating a collection of Controls with a loop

Tags: c#, winforms

So i'm basically attempting to create a grid out of pictureboxes through a for loop using the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            PictureBox tile = new PictureBox() ;
            tile.Size = new Size(49, 49);
            tile.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
            tile.Location = new Point((100 + (50 * i)), (100 + (50 * j)));
            Debug.WriteLine("PB created with index ["+i+","+j+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

But during runtime, the form appears blank, with no pictureboxes generated at all.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the control you just created to the form's Controls collection.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            PictureBox tile = new PictureBox() ;
            tile.Size = new Size(49, 49);
            tile.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
            tile.Location = new Point((100 + (50 * i)), (100 + (50 * j)));
            Debug.WriteLine("PB created with index ["+i+","+j+"]");

            // The control needs to be added to the form's Controls collection
            Controls.Add(tile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sorry for the nooby mistake :P

Comment: @IanH. Nope, WPF's layout engine and control management works *very* differently than WinForms.

Comment: @Craig Yeah sorry if I was unclear about my statement, what I meant was that it is much harder in WPF to add controls at runtime without deleting the old ones.